# API Gateway Best Practises

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are looking at utilising aws api gateway for better management of APIs. However, at a enterprise level, what will be the best practise? Will a common API gateway for to be used by all app teams be necessary (In this case, we might need a administrator for this common API gateway which adds to overhead) or should each app team build their own API gateway and administration of their API calls?

Hope to have someone share their experiences.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AWS API gateway for different web/mobile application projects. let me try to answer your questions one by one here.

**Limitations Based Design**

API gateway comes with limitations. You can find answers based on these limitations. 
For eg: There is a soft limit on "Resources per API" and its set at 300 which can be increased up to 500 max. This means that in future, if more than 500 resources are needed, new API gateway needs to be created.

So, it's better to logically segregate the APIs and have different API gateways depending on the purpose.

Throttle limit per region across REST APIs, WebSocket APIs, and WebSocket callback APIs is limited (Soft) to 10,000 requests per second (RPS) with an additional burst capacity provided by the token bucket algorithm, using a maximum bucket capacity of 5,000 requests.

So based on traffic API gateway needs to be designed.

There are many such limitations https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

**Features Based Design**

1. API Gateway uses OPEN API standards and facilitates XML/JSON import and export features. So if a new API Gateway is created with a swagger file from an application, its better not to mix it with other applications.
2. There are many features like 1)Enable API cache, 2)Enable throttling, 3) Web Application Firewall 4) Client Certificate which cannot be common for all APis in an enterprise. So again, it's better to have separate APIs based on the requirements.
3. AWS API Gateway is engineered with different logging mechanisms and each API gateway implementation will need a tailored approach.
4. SDK generation comes very handy for mobile development and again there is no use of bundling all apis into one SDk and providing access.

So my suggestion is to use multiple API gateways, for an enterprise based on specific needs.